# Manually updating installed signed APK

Tags: android

I have an app on google play store right now.I just move my p**revious java code to kotlin** since It is much easier for me. The package are all the same. Problem is on my android studio, when I try to execute the **release** variant I keep having this **install_failed_update_incompatible** error. On my searching, I have to **remove the old app**. Now I am a bit worried. I don't my user base to uninstall the app let alone erase all their data. Is there a way I could update the app without uninstalling it? Sort of like when you update an app from google play store? The data and information are retained except that the old apk is remove?

Everything is the same with my previous java project except that now I am using kotlin. package and even the apk signed key are all the same.

PS on emulator(genymotion) the updating works and even retained the previous information data. but on real device it won't

Comment: Have you tried incrementing your version code? Are you sure you're signing the app with the same certificate for the Java and Android versions?

Comment: @AutonomousApps yes, I am very sure that the certificate is the same. I run the old java version to emulator and then run the kotlin version and it works. However not for the real device. and yes I alos increment the version code

Comment: There's nothing about Kotlin per se that should cause this. There's some other issue.

Comment: @AutonomousApps True. But I can't figure out what exactly is the reason why I can't install on real device. It's just weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the apk file release from google play store is a bit different. I don't the difference. I have my old java project executed on release variant on my device and then execute the kotlin version release variant. The update went okay. However when I downloaded my app on google play store and then updated it with my new kotlin version release variant, it failed. Im not sure why but it seems that apk submitted to google play store is being modified.